# asp.net POST HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to do an HTTP POST using C# but I have not been able to find a good tutorial.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.71).aspx).

Refer to the sample in [this](http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx) article.

Comment: If you're going to fire off requests while handling an asp.net request, consider doing it asynchronously to improve the responsiveness of your site.